# How to keep update user interface on Windows Phone apps responsively

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to create an Calculator app on WP 8.1. I would like to create an Automation Button which perform automation click on other buttons of my app. For example, in this code, when I click the automation button, it will call the event of clicking other buttons such as:

```
private void Auto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button3_Click(this, null);
    button_addition_Click(this, null);
    button7_Click(this, null);
    button_result_Click(this, null);
}
```

I this example, I perform the operations is "3 + 7" and after that I press the "Equal" button.
The result created is right. But I have 1 issue, that is the showing of textbox's data don't change responsively in this method. But when I click the button3 independently, the showing of textbox's data changed instantly. The code button3_Click event is:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (is_subtend(this.textbox.Text) == false)
        this.textbox.Text += "3";
    else
        this.textbox.Text = "3";
}
```

So what can I do to change the showing of textbox's data in the automation_click event. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint: use `if( ! is_subtend(this.textbox.Text))` instead of `if( is_subtend(this.textbox.Text) == false)`. The outcome is the same, but it is much better style, for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The results are as expected.  There are really no delays in between those Button Clicks, so it changes the text really fast, no time for the UI to update.  If you want to see a "3" then... a "3+"... then a "3+7"... etc.. then implement a delay in-between the button clicks.

To see what I mean try this

```C#
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// don't forget the async
private async void Auto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    button3_Click(this, null);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
    button_addition_Click(this, null);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
    button7_Click(this, null);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
    button_result_Click(this, null);    
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
}
```

Lower the `250` to a value you want for the speed you're looking for.